# Setting count on set interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following code. Why is the `interval` happening only one time instead of 3, as expected on `let x= 3`?

Basically I need to repeat this loop/interval for 3 times but it is happening only once.

```js
$(function() {
  let colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']

  let x = 3;
  let interval = 6000;

  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('body').css('background-color', colors[i]);
      backtoWhite();

    }, i * interval)
  }

  function backtoWhite() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: All three start at the „same“ time. This is why you only see one change

Comment: When the timeout callback executes... Like 0 to 12 seconds after (depending on the timeout), `i` equals 3 for all of them. That's why.

Comment: This is like example #6 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/2159528)

Comment: Can you guys let me know how to add delay here? I thought the `let interval = 6000;` is taking care of this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: This seems to be running 3 times. Your delays are 0, 6000 and 1200 ms. I see a red background for 3000 ms, a white background for 3000 ms, then blue, then green. What's the expected behavior?

Comment: Your title and question both mention `setInterval()`, but the code uses `setTimeout()`. Which are you really asking about?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to execute a function continuously whereas a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) executes a function once after a specified delay (in milliseconds).

The documentation for `setInterval` states that:

> The setInterval() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. It returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the interval, so you can remove it later by calling clearInterval().

The documentation for `setTimeout` states that:

> The setTimeout() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin (and successor to window.setTimeout) sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once after the timer expires.

```js
$(function() {
  let colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']

  let x = 0;
  let interval = 6000;
  
  var intvl = setInterval(function(){
      $('body').css('background-color', colors[x]);
      setTimeout(function(){
      backtoWhite();
      }, interval/2);
      x++;
      if(x>=3){
        clearInterval(intvl);
      }
    }, interval);

  function backtoWhite() {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code structure, you can achieve what you want this way:

```js
$(function() {
  let colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']

  const nbColors = colors.length;
  let repetition = 3;
  let interval = 6000;

  for (let loop = 0 ; loop < repetition ; loop++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < nbColors; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('body').css('background-color', colors[i]);
          backtoWhite();

        }, (i + loop * nbColors) * interval)
      }
  }

  function backtoWhite() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
    }, interval / 2);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But this is missing the great potential of functional programming. You should consider using `callback`s to trigger the next color change once the current has finished instead of triggering all at once with different delay in execution.

Answer (score 0):

Using one `interval`, the color change, cycling the color array can be done like this.
There is a white color applied in between each color change.

```js
$(function() {
  let colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
  let index = 0;
  let whiteInBetween = false;  // A "flag" to toggle at each iteration to determine if to apply white instead of color.

  setInterval(function() {
    if(whiteInBetween){
      $('body').css('background-color', "white");
    }else{
      $('body').css('background-color', colors[index]);
      index++
    }
    whiteInBetween = !whiteInBetween;  // "Flag" toggling
    index = index%colors.length;  // Keeping the color index in range, using the remainder of the index divided by the color array length
    
  },1000);  // Interval setted faster for this demo...  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is executing way faster than your `timeout`, so you're probably only seeing the first or last iteration. When dealing with timing, I'd recommend less variables and more recursion or callbacks.

Also, I'm assuming you want the time for each color to be constant, since `red` has an index of `0` and `i * interval` would mean you never see red.

```js
let colors = ['red','white','blue','white','green','white'];

function SetBackgroundColor(colorIndex) {
    colorIndex = colorIndex >= colors.length - 1 ? 0 : ++colorIndex; //constrain index  
    
    $('body').css({'background-color': colors[colorIndex]}); //set color
    
    setTimeout(
      function() { SetBackgroundColor(colorIndex); }, //recursion
      colors[colorIndex] === 'white' ? 3000 : 6000); //select timeout
}

SetBackgroundColor(-1); //initialize
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```